# Need to generate the format list from user input (without '.', ',') in Angular 6

Tags: regex, angular, angular6

I am having a form in Angular which gets the file format as input for Eg: `.txt, .zip, .tar.gz`

when a user submits the form, I have to just extract the formats without `[any spaces,'.'(dot/period), and ','(comma)]` and return as a list

for Eg: `{"formats":["txt","zip","tar.gz"]}`

Here is my code, in my `component.ts`

```
const format_lists = this.form.get('files') as FormArray;

for (let i = 0; i < format_lists.length; i++) {        
this.form.value.files[i].formats = this.form.value.files[i].formats.replace(/[.,]/g, ' ');
  }
for (let i = 0; i < format_lists.length; i++) {

this.form.value.files[i].formats = this.form.value.files[i].formats.split(' ') ;
this.form.value.files[i].formats = this.form.value.files[i].formats.filter(String);

}
```

What I am doing here is (my form has a multiple file format input, so I am iterating through all the available inputs) replacing the `'.',','` with spaces (This is the part I need to change, I guess) so my input looks like this `txt  zip   tar gz`, then use `split(' ')` by space to make it as a list, which makes it look like this `["","txt","","zip","","","","","tar","","gz"]`. Finally when I use `.filer(String)`, it becomes like this `["txt","zip","tar","gz"]`

but my expected output is `["txt","zip","tar.gz"]`. What changes should I make to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Input (user enters this in form field): `.txt, .zip, .tar.gz`

Desired output: `["txt","zip","tar.gz"]` (as an array list)

Comment: please could you state very clearly, INITIAL INPUT = someting, DESIRED OUTPUT = something

Comment: Is it clear now? @danday74

Comment: the input is a string? ".txt, .zip, .tar.gz" ???

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Input is a string.

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code using your given input it logs your desired output.

```js
const input = ".txt, .zip, .tar.gz"

const parts = input.split(' ')

const output = parts.map(x => x.replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I appreciate your effort. It would be nice if you help me out with the follow-up issue.  Just to test the code, I gave inputs like this `.. ., .tar.gf.ds ,.tar` and I got the output as `[".","","tar.gf.ds","tar"]`. Is there any workaround to prevent this from happening?

Comment: and also for the inputs like `tar tar.gz zip` the generated output is `["tar","targz","zip"]` but the expected output is `["tar","tar.gz","zip"]`

Comment: if you create a new question, clearly stating actual inputs and desired outputs, I will answer it - glad it helped :) pop me a link to the new question in these comments.

Comment: BTW the replace function is replacing the first occurrence only - so in my code x.replace(',', '') is replacing the first comma (if any) with nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758176/remove-and-in-the-beginning-end-of-every-element-from-the-array-list-in-angu

Comment: I have created a new question with specifics, can you please take a look at the provided link.