# Remove . and , in the beginning/end of every element from the array list in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a reactive form in Angular which gets file format as text input

```
<input type="text" name="formats" formControlName= "formats">
```

Eg: `.txt, .zip, .tar.gz`

I needed to convert those inputs as an array list. With the help of @danday74, I can able to do that. here is the code:

```
const input = ".txt, .zip, .tar.gz"

const parts = input.split(' ')

const output = parts.map(x => x.replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))

console.log(output)
```

The output generated by the code is `["txt","zip","tar.gz"]`, which is what I expected.

However, my concern is, if a user enters something like this `.. ., .tar.gf.ds ,.tar` or `tar tar.gz zip` the output will be `[".","","tar.gf.ds","tar"]` and `["tar","targz","zip"]` respectively

My question is how do I implement this in such a way that a user can enter the file format without any specific structure (for Eg: `.txt, .zip, .tar.gz,` `.txt .zip .tar.gz`, `txt, zip, tar.gz`, `txt zip tar.gz` ) and I should be able to generate the output like this  `["txt","zip","tar.gz"]`. like I should be able to neglect the input if it is just `..` or `.,` and only consider the input with string.

Comment: This question isn't really specific to Angular. You might get more answers if you just focus your question on the JavaScript to process the array.

Comment: Hello Navaneeth my friend, you have some answers already - if you get stuck add a comment here and ill take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only concerned about leading `.` and `,`, you could use a regex as follows:

```js
const input = '.txt, .zip, .tar.gz, ,.tar, txt, zip, tar.gz, .., .,'

const output = input.split(', ')
  .map(ext => ext.replace(/^\W+/, '')) // remove any character that's not a word character from the beginning of each string
  .filter(Boolean); // filter just to remove empty strings

console.log(output);
```

If you also need to remove trailing characters you could modify the regex to remove them from the end as well:

```js
const input = '.txt, .zip, .tar.gz, ,.tar, txt, zip, tar.gz, .txt., .tar.gz., ,.tar,., .., .,'

const output = input.split(' ') // split on space character as trailing commas will be handled in the regex
  .map(ext => ext.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, ''))
  .filter(Boolean);

console.log(output);
```

Let me know if there are any other considerations.

Comment: Instead of `input.split(', ')`, I just used `input.split(' ')` because `ext.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, ''))` will remove the comma. So it will work for the input like this one `txt zip tar.gz`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to reflect that use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general way how you can do it!

If there are two `..` anywhere in the string! Do not add it.

Some use cases might have been left, comment if there are any

```js
var strings = [
  ".txt, .zip, .tar.gz",
  "..txt .zip .tar.gz a.b.should.be.in", 
  "txt, zip, tar.gz",
  ".., ..., ...., .this.should.be.in, .not..this"
]

var extensions = []

strings
  .forEach((item) => {
    let items = item.split(',');
    if (items.length <= 1) {
      items = item.split(' ');
    }
    items.forEach(ext => {
      const trimedExt = ext.trim()
      if (
        trimedExt.indexOf('..') === -1
      ) {
        if (trimedExt[0] === '.') {
          extensions.push(trimedExt.substr(1))
        } else {
          extensions.push(trimedExt)
        }        
      }
    });
  })
  
 console.log(extensions)
```

Comment: Quadratic time complexity, why now?

Comment: @AderemiDayo The outer loop is just feeding in the inputs. If the inner loop is made into a function and just fed with inputs, it will look like linear time complex solution

Comment: @Prasanna Thank you for your suggestion. Much appreciated!